# Native pointers in managed class

Tags: c++, .net, memory-management, c++-cli

I was doing some C++/CLI programming recently in order to integrate some of our company's native C++ classes into .NET. My question may sound trivial, but this is one thing I'm always not sure about:
If there is a ref class with a native pointer, say

```
public ref class ManagedClass {  
    private:  
        NativeClass* pObj1;  
        NativeClass* pObj2;  
        void DoStuff(NativeClass* obj);  
    public:  
        ManagedClass();  
        bool Activate();  
}
```

and a constructor like

```
ManagedClass::ManagedClass() : pObj1(new NativeClass()), pObj2(new NativeClass()) {;}
```

instances of that class will be created on the managed heap. However, `pObj1` and `pObj2` do point to objects created on the native heap? So there is no pinning needed to use those pointers, even since they are members of a managed class? Especially, if the `DoStuff` function calles a external native library function, say

```
void ManagedClass::DoStuff(NativeClass* obj) {  
    int returnCode = External::Function(obj);  
    if (returnCode == 0) return true;  
    else return false;  
}
```

is there no need to write something like `pin_ptr<NativeClass> pinPtr = obj` etc.? I guess the situation is different if a *reference* to the pointer is needed; here, however, I understand that the location of the pointer itself may vary due to memory reallocation, but its content, i.e. a memory adress on the native heap, stays valid since the garbage collector won't touch that memory. Is this correct and code like the one above safe to use?
Thanks for your help!

Matthew

Comment: Yes, this is correct and the code shown in the question is OK. Don't forget to release these pointers by properly implementing `Dispose` pattern.

Answer (score 1):

To your question the code you posted is correct and will work.

In my opinion it would be preferable(cleaner\safer) to use C++\CLI as a wrapper to your C++ native classes so all the public methods should receive only managed objects as parameters otherwise just use `COM`

Comment: To be honest, I would not touch `COM` unless I really have to. I think C++/CLI is very powerful, so why use it for wrapping only? However I agree that public functions should only take managed objects so that the class can neatly integrate in e.g. a C# GUI. The `DoStuff` function above is private, though.

Comment: @Matz i didnt mean that c++\cli should be only a wrapper what i was trying to say is that all the advantages of c++\cli is lost the second your public methods start receiving native poiners so as long as you avoid it everyting should be great and you'll be able to integrate native c++ with c#